# Seemingly impossible differential equation $ y' = \sqrt{|y|(1-y)}$ with $y < 0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been staring at the following seemingly easy differential equation problem for a couple of hours now and I cannot seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'd really appreciate if someone could provide a hint (rather than present an all worked out answer) to me.

The differential equation is

$$ y' = \sqrt{|y|(1-y)}, \hspace{1cm} y < 0 $$

I proceeded in the following manner: rewrite to account for the $y < 0$ condition to $y' = \sqrt{y^2-y}$. Separate variables and then integrate to get rid of the derivative

$$ \int \frac{y'}{\sqrt{y^2 - y}}dx = \int dx \Rightarrow y = \frac{\cosh(x + C) + 1}{2} > 0$$

So it seems to me that there is no solution, yet there is asked for one. I integrated by first completing squares, substituting $u = y - \frac{1}{2}$, multiplying by 2 to remove fraction in denominator, substituting $s = 2u$ to obtain the standard integral $\int \frac{s'}{\sqrt{s^2 - 1}} dx = \cosh^{-1}(s)$ and finally substituting everything back (and then solve for $y$ of course).

EDIT:

I decided to add all my integration steps explicitly to remove any ambiguity of what I did. So

$$ \int \frac{y'}{\sqrt{y^2 - y}}dx = \int dx \Rightarrow \int \frac{y'}{\sqrt{(y-\frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{1}{4}}}dx = \int dx \underbrace{\Rightarrow}_{u = y - \frac{1}{2}} \int \frac{u'}{\sqrt{u^2-\frac{1}{4}}}dx = \int dx$$

$$ \Rightarrow 2 \int \frac{u'}{\sqrt{4u^2-1}}dx = \int dx \underbrace{\Rightarrow}_{s = 2u} \int \frac{s'}{\sqrt{s^2 - 1}}dx = \int dx \underbrace{\Rightarrow}_{\text{integral for arccosh}} \cosh^{-1}(s) = x + C$$

$$ \Rightarrow s = \cosh(x + C) \Rightarrow y = \frac{\cosh(x + C) + 1}{2} > 0$$

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+1%2F%28sqrt%28x^2-x%29%29+dx seems to disagree with one of your steps (they get an inverse sinh instead of inverse cosh).

Comment: @Ian They are the same function (the function your link leads to and arccosh). Plot them in GeoGebra to see. Don't know why Wolfram is making it look so complex...

Comment: Since $s \lt -1$ and domain of $acosh(s)$ is $s \ge 1$, the integral should be $acosh(-s)$

Comment: you need one more sub, $t=-s$, before applying your integral (which is meaningless as cosh is not globally invertible)

Comment: The equation has a solution for all $x>0$ because the function $y\mapsto \sqrt{|y|(1-y)}$ is Lipschitz-continuous

Comment: Are you sure that the differential equation is $y'=\sqrt{|y|(1-y)}$? Could it be $(y')^2=|y|(1-y)$ instead? This last one indeed has negative solutions, for example $y=-\sinh^2(x/2)$.

Comment: @OskarLimka No, the function is not Lipschitz at $y=0$.

Comment: @NessunDorma The differential equation $y' = \sqrt{|y|(1-y)}$ has negative solutions, where is the problem?

Comment: @Did, I don't know why everyone is providing complete answers (some obviously wrong though), I only asked for a hint or more importantly the place I went wrong.

Comment: @Jori Yes I saw that you took care to state this unambiguously, and yet (blind answering machines, I guess). Re the correctness of the answers you received, ODE is a notoriously badly taught subject... Re the question you asked, the faulty step is at $\implies$ and the trouble is that, later on, "the standard integral" is not $\cosh^{-1}(s)$ (cannot be, since $s<-1$).

Comment: @Did if I explicitly add all me steps, will you then be so kind to make an answer? Perhaps I shouldn't have done it like this, but rather write everything out. Give me a second I'll change it.

Comment: @Did I edited the question. I'd really appreciate if you'd take a look!

Comment: Yes, and the trouble is still at the step I said before: a primitive of $1/\sqrt{s^2-1}$ valid on $s<-1$ is $-\cosh^{-1}(-s)$ (but not the nonexistent $\cosh^{-1}(s)$). Using it yields $-\cosh^{-1}(-s)=x+c$, and since $1-2y=-2u=-s=\cosh(x+c)$, one gets $y=\frac12(1-\cosh(x+c))=-\sinh^2\left(\frac12(x+c)\right)$, QED.

Comment: For this case a quick hint may not suffice.

Comment: @Narasimham Huh? The first sentence of my last comment makes for a decent hint, I believe.

Comment: @Did Aaahhh, well that explains a lot. I looked that integral up from a table and it said noting about the validness of the range (the same goes for Wolfram http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+1%2Fsqrt%28x%5E2-1%29). I already wondered about it because then the integral wouldn't exist on some range, which could be but didn't seem likely in this case.

Comment: Yup. Please replace the last sentence of my previous comment by "and since $1-2y=-2u=-s=\cosh(x+c)$ on $x+c<0$, one gets $y=\frac12(1-\cosh(x+c))=-\sinh^2\left(\frac12(x+c)\right)$ on $x+c<0$, QED."

Comment: Thanks, I saw my error in reading the problem first line  itself  :(  so deleted, and after correction solution appears  to tally, but not posting it.

Comment: @Did, well spotted, I was looking at $y\to\infty$, which is where it matters for existence, but I agree that uniqueness (e.g., if for $y(0)=0$) could fail.

Answer (score 3):

$$ y' = \sqrt{|y|(1-y)}, \hspace{1cm} y < 0 $$
Let $z=-y$  hence $|y]=|z|=z$ in $z>0$
$$ -z' = \sqrt{z(1+z)}, \hspace{1cm} z > 0 $$
$$z=\sinh^2\left(\tfrac12(x-c)\right)$$
$$y=-\sinh^2\left(\tfrac12(x-c)\right)$$

$$y'=-\sinh\left(\tfrac12(x-c)\right)\cosh\left(\tfrac12(x-c)\right)$$
$y'>0$ implies $\sinh\left(\tfrac12(x-c)\right)<0$ hence $x-c<0$

This limits the range of $x$ and the solution is :

> $$y=-\sinh^2\left(\tfrac12(x-c)\right) \qquad x <c $$